# contractions as "half" words?

Tags: contractions

There's a quirk that I keep seeing in [*Worm*](https://parahumans.wordpress.com) :  Whenever the author wants to draw attention to very short, dramatic statements, he refers to them as being "**two and a half words**."

Examples:

> I'm sorry.
>   He's here.

I would call them *two* words, but maybe that's just me.    I was taught that a contraction turns two words into one.

Is it a *Canadian* difference in contractions?  (The action of the book and first person narrator is from the U.S., but the author is from Canada somewhere.)  Is it just a quirk from Wildbow (J.C. McCrae), the author?

Comment: I just looked up *I'm* in both [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/I%27m) and [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/i'm) They each provide a dictionary definition for it, making it, in their view, a single word. It could be considered *one word* in the same way that open compound words (for example, *banana split* and *hot dog*) are considered *single words*. It all depends on perspective. Saying that something is (or includes) a *half word*, however, is not something I'd heard before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from a work of fiction, not a grammar, the product of a storyteller, not a linguist. Do not take artistic expressions too literally. The characters are not conducting a census.

---

Linguists may debate what the definition of a *word* actually is (it's something in between a morpheme and a phrase), but in no case would you be calculating some sort of decimal value to determine whether something is a whole word or not. The *and a half* simply indicates that from the author's perspective, a contraction should be counted as being greater than two words, perhaps because the presence of the apostrophe calls attention to the clipped middle word. But that is just a creative way of thinking about them. The author could also write that the sun *burns*, but that doesn't mean that the word *burn* means *undergoes nuclear fusion* in Canada.

I'm answering the question, however, as it may be useful for English learners to be aware that *and a half* is frequently used metaphorically for situations like this, where something obviously cannot be fractional, but a strict count of wholes does not seem to express adequately the value of the collective. *Half* is the most common, as it is the most basic fraction. You may come across *quarter* from time to time to indicate something that is a smaller fraction, but again, it is not the point to assign a precise numerical valuation to something.

Consider as an example someone with two young children and a puppy dog. You would not expect her to say she has three kids (although this is actually becoming more common), as obviously a puppy is not the same as a human child, and does not receive anything close to an equal share of time, money, or affection. Nevertheless, the investment in the puppy is significant, and requires a major adjustment of her lifestyle. Thus, in informal situations, she might joke that she is caring for *two and a half children*; this establishes that she is not treating all three as exactly equal (as a more clinical expression like *three dependents* might) but also that the addition of the puppy is at least analogous to having another child in the household.

In a different but similar sense, consider the long-running U.S. television sitcom *[Two and a Half Men](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0369179/)*. The title is taken from the situation, in which a man and his 10-year old son move in with his hedonistic brother. The son is starting to come of age, and so more than a boy. Still, he is not a full-fledged man either. He is counted as a "half man." This may also allude to the idea of *[two and a half kids](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/378244/t)*, a different expression referring to the average size of an American household.